# Awk - print next record following matched record

Tags: awk

I'm trying to get a next field after matching field using awk.

Is there an option to do that or do I need to scan the record into array then check each field in array and print the one after that?

What I have so far:

The file format is:

```
<FIELD><separator "1"><VALUE><separator "1"><FIELD><separator "1"><VALUE>
```

... and so on, `field|value` pairs are repeated, will be at least one pair in line or multiple pairs <10 per line

dat.txt:

```
FIELDA01VALUEA01FIELDA21VALUEA21FIELDA31VALUEA3
FIELDB01VALUEB01FIELDB21VALUEB21FIELDB31VALUEB3
FIELDC01VALUEC01FIELDC21VALUEC21FIELDC31VALUEC3
FIELDD01VALUED01FIELDD21VALUED21FIELDD31VALUED3
FIELDE01VALUEE01FIELDE21VALUEE21FIELDE31VALUEE3
```

With simple awk script which prints the second field on a line matching FIELDB2:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "1" }
/FIELDB2/ { print $2 }
```

Running the above:

```
> ./scrpt.awk dat.txt
```

Gives me:

```
VALUEB0
```

This is because the line that match:

```
FIELDB01VALUEB01FIELDB21VALUEB21FIELDB31VALUEB3
```

When split into records looks:

```
FIELDB0 VALUEB0 FIELDB2 VALUEB2 FIELDB3 VALUEB3
```

From which the second field is `VALUEB0`

Now I don't know which `FIELDXX` will match but I would like to print the next record on the line after `FIELDXX` that matched, in this specific example when `FIELDB2` matches I need to print `VALUEB2`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can match the line, then loop over the fields for a match, and print the next record:

```
awk -F1 '/FIELDB2/ { for (x=1;x<=NF;x++) if ($x~"FIELDB2") print $(x+1) }'
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for slowing things down using a loop :)

```
awk -F1 '/FIELDB2/ {f=NR} f&&NR-1==f' RS="1" file
VALUEB2
```

Comment: That works like a charm! Would you mind explaining though?
I mostly don't understand the order in this condition "f&&NR-1==f", is it this way ((NR-1)==f)&&f?
I suspect you use NR-1 to match FIELDB2 and thus let NR be the next field but I can't understand how it's done and what are the values of NR and f regarding the matching pattern. Thank you in advance

Comment: I think this is saying that when we hit FIELDB2, set `f` to its record number.  Separately if `f` has been set and the current record number minus 1 is equal to `f`, execute the default action which is to print the line (which is the field because of `RS`).