# print from match & process several input files

Tags: awk, gawk

when you scrutiny my questions from the past weeks you find I asked questions similar to this one. I had problems to ask in a demanded format since I did not really know where my problems came from. E. Morton tells me not to use range expression. Well, I do not know what they are excactly. I found in this forum many questions alike mine with working answers.

Like: "How to print following line from a match" ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033385/print-all-rows-following-matched-row?noredirect=1&lq=1))

But all solutions I found stop working when I process more than one input file. I need to process many.
I use this command:

```
gawk -f 1.awk print*.csv > new.txt
```

while 1.awk contains:

```
    BEGIN { OFS=FS=";"
pattern="row4"
}
go {print} $0 ~ pattern {go = 1}
```

input file 1 print1.csv contains:

```
row1;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row2;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row3;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row4;don't;need;to;match;the;whole;line,;
row5;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row6;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row7;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row8;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row9;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row10;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
```

Input file 2 print2.csv contains the same just for illustration purpose.

The 1.awk (and several others ways I found in this forum to print from match) works for one file. Output:

```
row5;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row6;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row7;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row8;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row9;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row10;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
```

BUT not when I process more input files.
Each time I process this way more than one input file awk commands 'to print from match' seem to be ignored.
As said I was told not to use range expression. I do not know how and maybe the problem is linked to the way I input several files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just reset your match indicator at the beginning of each file

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{p=0} p; /row4/{p=1} ' file1 file2

row5;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row6;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row7;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row8;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row9;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row10;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row5;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row6;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row7;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row8;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row9;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
row10;something;in;this;row;;;;;;;
```

**UPDATE**

From the comments

> is it possible to combine your awk with: "If $1="row5" then write in
>   $6="row5" and delete the value "row5" in $5? In other words, to move
>   content "row5" in column1, if found there, to new column 6? I could to
>   this with another awk but a combination into one would be nicer

```
... $1=="row5"{$6=$5; $5=""} ...
```

or, if you want to use another field instead of `$5` replace `$5` with the corresponding field number.

Comment: As per OP there could be many files, then it may give error like too many files opened etc, I guess.

Comment: Your guess is not correct.  The input files are processed one at a time and properly closed.

Comment: Thank you karakfa. Eventually it works and I am a step nearer to my goal. Out of curiosity... is it possible to combine your awk with: "If $1="row5" then write in $6="row5" and delete the value "row5" in $5? In other words, to move content "row5" in column1, if found there, to new column 6? I could to this with another awk but a combination into one would be nicer.